# How to blend text to background so it looks burned in paint.net?

Tags: text, paint.net

I'm working on artwork for which currently looks like this:

[image: Artwork]

It currently has 3 layers:

1. The white background which I'll delete later.
2. The image of the photo.
3. The text.

Currently the text is just placed on top of the image of the photo and they don't really blend well. I'd like to achieve an effect close to what you see below:

[image]

What can I do to blend the text better on the photo image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some ideas. You can use one, a combination, or all of the following:

1. Set the colour of the text to brown, similar to the colour of the edges of the burnt photograph.
2. Slightly reduce the opacity of the text layer in the Layer Options (F4)
3. Choose [a layer blend mode](https://www.getpaint.net/doc/latest/BlendModes.html) other than *Normal* for the text layer. You may have to experiment with different blend modes.

Answer (score 4):

**ADD:** This is accidentally made for Photoshop, Paint.NET hasn't suggested adjustment layers.

Remove the whitening under the text or have it everywhere, the background should be the same. Now you underline "This is inserted".

You have already detoriated the text quite well. No more suggestions about it.

But the color! It must fit better. Try this:

[image]

The text isn't visible at all as a layer. It's placed as white on black to layer masks of adjustment layers. Curves layer increases contrast and Hue&Saturation layer colorizes to brown. The mask is blurred in Hue&Saturation layer to make some spread. The same can be achieved also with layer style Outer Glow if it's applied to normal text layer.

You can take layer mask onscreen for edits (=for pasting in place here) by clicking the layer mask ícon and pressing Alt at the same time.

Here's another view which shows the curves layer:

[image]